# Can I publish build info when when pushing a npm .tgz to Artifactory?

Tags: jenkins, npm, jenkins-pipeline, artifactory

How can I publish build info when when pushing a npm registry to Artifactory?

I can do it with Maven using [these steps](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Working+With+Pipeline+Jobs+in+Jenkins#WorkingWithPipelineJobsinJenkins-MavenBuildswithArtifactory)

```
def rtMaven = Artifactory.newMavenBuild()

def buildInfo = rtMaven.run pom: 'maven-example/pom.xml', goals: 'clean install'
```

Currently I am just using `npm publish`

But I would like to have Builds info for my tgz files. Is it possible?

Thanks!

Comment: You can publish your npm packages using File Specs, instead of npm publish. With this method you can generate build info for your published packages. See the details in the same link.

Answer (score 1):

here a sample pipeline code doing simple build.
The only thouble with this script is that i can't figure out how to fill dependencies informations.

```
node {
   stage('Cleaning') {
       deleteDir()
   }
   stage('Preparing') { // for display purposes
      // Get some code from Git
      git credentialsId: 'MyGitCredential', url: 'http://gitRepourl/MyGitProject.git'
   }
   stage('Fetch Dependencies') {
      // Run the node build
      nodejs(nodeJSInstallationName: 'MyNode', configId: 'aaaaaaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaaaaaaaaaa') {
        sh 'npm install'
      }
   }
   stage('Build') {
      // Run the node build                              
      nodejs(nodeJSInstallationName: 'MyNode', configId: 'aaaaaaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaaaaaaaaaa') {
        sh 'npm pack'
      }
   }
   stage('Test') {
      // Run the node build
      nodejs(nodeJSInstallationName: 'MyNode', configId: 'aaaaaaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaaaaaaaaaa') {
        sh 'npm run test'
      }
   }
   stage('Results') {
      junit 'test-results.xml' // need to setup karma junit reporter
      archive 'myArtefact-*.tgz'
   }
   stage('Artifactory') {
       def uploadSpec = """{
          "files": [
            {
              "pattern": "myArtefact-*.tgz",
              "target": "artifactory-npm-repo/myArtefact/"
            }
         ]
        }"""
        def server = Artifactory.server 'MyArtifactory'
        def buildInfo = server.upload(uploadSpec)
        buildInfo.retention maxBuilds: 2
        server.publishBuildInfo(buildInfo)
   }
}
```

But with this, you've got your build ans artifacts in artifactory